# Getting a 91 error on a For...Each loop while using HTML objects

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I have a script I have developed using the HTML Object Library that looks for text information in specific HTML class nodes.

My script - which uses a `For...Each` loop and the `.getElementsByClassName` property - works fine most of the time but doesn't when there is missing information.

This part of the webpage source code displays **ONE** contact information:

```
<div class="Contact Information" ng-class="{'selected-activity-date': marche.hasSelectedActivity('participation.societes_intervenantes.' + intervenant.societe.id)}">
      <div class="slide-title">
        <span class="Activity" ng-bind="::intervenant.role.libelle">Design</span>
        <span>:</span>
      </div>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <span ng-switch="" on="::intervenant.societe.isHorsReferentiel">
            <a class="Company Name" href="#/societes/41799459700033?from=22559491" ui-sref="societes.detail({id: intervenant.societe.id, from: marche.marche_id})" ng-bind-html="::intervenant.societe.raison_sociale |&nbsp;trusted" ng-switch-default="">Agency Design Cie</a>
          </span>
        </li>
        <li class="Address Line 1"></li>
        <li class="Address Line 2">93  Charlington Road </li>
        <li class="Address Line 3"></li>
        <li class="Postal Code & City">57525
          BARTONTOWN
        </li>
        <li class="Telephone Number" ng-if="::intervenant.societe.telephone">
          <span class="vpicon vpicon-telephone"></span>
          <a class="ng-binding" href="tel:0387716854">0387716854</a>
        </li>
        <li class="Email Address" ng-if="::intervenant.societe.email">
          <span class="vpicon vpicon-mail"></span>
          <a class="grey-no-underline ng-binding" href="mailto:agency@design.com">agency@design.com
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I've summarized it to make it easier to read:

```
<div class="Contact Information">
    <span class="Activity">Design</span>
    <a class="Company Name">Agency Design Cie</a>
    <li class="Address Line 1"></li>
    <li class="Address Line 2">93 Charlington Road</li>
    <li class="Address Line 3"></li>
    <li class="Postal Code & City">57525 BARTONTOWN</li>
    <li class="Telephone Number">0387716854</a>
    <li class="Email Address">agency@design.com</a>
</div>
```

**My script works fine in scraping the information of one contact.**

#### *However*

Most of the time I get three different contact information. In this example, the 2nd contact has no telephone or email information:

```
<div class="Contact Information n°1">
    <span class="Activity">Design</span>
    <a class="Company Name">Agency Design Cie</a>
    <li class="Address Line 1"></li>
    <li class="Address Line 2">93 Charlington Road</li>
    <li class="Address Line 3"></li>
    <li class="Postal Code & City">57525 BARTONTOWN</li>
    <li class="Telephone Number">0387716854</a>
    <li class="Email Address">agency@design.com</a>
</div>

<div class="Contact Information n°2">
    <span class="Activity">Architect</span>
    <a class="Company Name">Architect Cie</a>
    <li class="Address Line 1"></li>
    <li class="Address Line 2">45 Belvery Hills</li>
    <li class="Address Line 3"></li>
    <li class="Postal Code & City">45023 LOS PEPITOS</li>
    <li class="Telephone Number"></a>
    <li class="Email Address"></a>
</div>

<div class="Contact Information n°3">
    <span class="Activity">Interior</span>
    <a class="Company Name">Accoustic Sound Cie</a>
    <li class="Address Line 1"></li>
    <li class="Address Line 2">78 Harley Road</li>
    <li class="Address Line 3"></li>
    <li class="Postal Code & City">65741 KILT</li>
    <li class="Telephone Number">0865963621</a>
    <li class="Email Address">accoustic@sound.com</a>
</div>
```

When the script runs, it will fill in my Excel sheet correctly for the 1st contact.

But it will fill in the telephone & email information from the 3rd (last) contact in the line of the 2nd and will then trigger a **91 error**.

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+
|  Activity |    Company Name     | Address Line 1 |    Address Line 2   | Address Line 3 | Postal Code & City | Telephone Number |        Email        |
+-----------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+---------------------+
|   Design  |  Agency Design Cie  |    (blank)     | 93 Charlington Road |     (blank)    | 57525 BARTONTOWN   |    0387716854    |  agency@design.com  |
| Architect |    Architect Cie    |    (blank)     |   45 Belvery Hills  |     (blank)    | 45023 LOS PEPITOS  |    0865963621    | accoustic@sound.com |
|   Design  | Accoustic Sound Cie |    (blank)     |    78 Harley Road   |     (blank)    | 65741 KILT         |     (blank)      |        (blank)      |
```

[image: Error 91]

> Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

The error highlights the following line:

```
TexteTelephone = Trim(CStr(TELEPHONE.innerText))
```

My script:

```
Sub ScrapingScript()

    Dim InternetWindow As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set InternetWindow = FindingExistingIE("AmazingWebsite") 'Calls a function to identify the existing IE tab named "AmazingWebsite"
    
    Dim SecondInternetWindow As Object
    Set SecondInternetWindow = New InternetExplorer
    
    SecondInternetWindow.Visible = True
    SecondInternetWindow.Navigate InternetWindow.LocationURL
    
    Do While SecondInternetWindow.Busy = True Or SecondInternetWindow.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Loop
    
    Dim IEDocument As HTMLDocument
    Set IEDocument = SecondInternetWindow.Document
    
    Dim BDDsheet As Variant
    Set BDDsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AmazingWebsiteSheet")
    BDDsheet.Activate
    
    Dim AllContacts As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set AllContacts = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName("Contact Information")
    Dim Contact As IHTMLElement

    (...) 'Similar declaration of the other class information (Company Name, Activity, Address...) 

    Dim TelephoneClass As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set TelephoneClass = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName("Telephone Number")
    Dim Telephone As IHTMLElement
    Dim TelephoneText As String
    
    Dim EmailClass As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set EmailClass = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName("email ng-scope")
    Dim Email As IHTMLElement
    Dim EmailText As String
    
    Dim Nb As Integer
    Nb = 0
    '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    For Each Contact In AllContacts
        Dim emptyRow As Long
        emptyRow = Worksheets("AmazingWebsiteSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("AmazingWebsiteSheet").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = (emptyRow) - 1
        Set Contact = AllContacts.Item(Nb)
        
        Set Telephone = TelephoneClass.Item(Nb)
        TelephoneText = Trim(CStr(Telephone.innerText))
        If TELEPHONE Is Nothing Then 'Checks if the HTML class has any value/entry. If so, it scrapes the text. If not, it will skip to the next part.
            GoTo EmailScrapingPart
        Else
            Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = TelephoneText
        End If
                
EmailScrapingPart:
        Set Email = EmailClass.Item(Nb)
        If Email Is Nothing Then 'Checks if the HTML class has any value/entry. If so, it scrapes the text. If not, it will skip to the next part.
            GoTo RestOfCode
        Else
            EmailText = Trim(CStr(Email.innerText))
            Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = Trim(EmailText)
        End If
        
RestOfCode:
        
        Nb = Nb + 1
        
        Set TELEPHONE = Nothing
        Set EmailouURL = Nothing

    Next Contact

SecondInternetWindow.Quit                                
MsgBox "Done"

End

End Sub
```

## My question:

What did I miss?

I ran a shortened version of the script with `Debug.Print` and `MsgBox()` to follow the number of iteration. During the 2nd iteration, the script jumps straight to the 3rd when dealing with the telephone & email HTML classes that hold no value.

Note: it works fine when all 3 contacts have a telephone & an email address.

Comment: Can you check the length of `Telephone.innerText` before using it?  You are currently checking it's something after you've tried to use it.  Maybe put the extraction in the `Else` part of that if

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, the length is always the same and does not cause any problem for the first & second iteration. My problem is that the script scrapes off the information from the 3rd iteration because it thinks "oh there's no information in the 2nd so I'll skip to the 3rd"

Comment: Why are you opening a new window with the same URL when you already have a reference to a window with that URL?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams! To be honest, it's how my script evolved throughout various errors. Also because I didn't think it would be possible to use an existing IE tab for the script (I started off from a basic tutorial on web-scraping that involves creating a new IE window). But if it is, I'll give it a try!

Comment: You should be able to use the reference from `FindingExistingIE` without needing to open a new IE instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in regards to the initial question, it seems that my initial script needed a separate function from the main Sub which will retrieve the email and telephone information by counting the number of characters (`.Length`).

I edited a few code lines of @Tim Williams' script, which now works for me:

```
Public IEDocument As HTMLDocument
Sub ScrapingScript()

    Dim InternetWindow As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim SecondInternetWindow As Object
    Dim BDDsheet As Worksheet
    Dim emptyRow As Range
    
    Set InternetWindow = FindingExistingIE("AmazingWebsite")
    If InternetWindow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "IE window not found!", vbExclamation
    End If
    Set IEDocument = InternetWindow.Document
    
    Set BDDsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AmazingWebsiteSheet")
    BDDsheet.Activate
    
    For Each Contact In AllContacts
        Dim emptyRow As Long
        emptyRow = Worksheets("AmazingWebsiteSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("AmazingWebsiteSheet").Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = (emptyRow) - 1
        Cells(emptyRow, 16).Value = subValue(Contact, "Telephone Number")
        Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = subValue(Contact, "email ng-scope")

    Next Contact

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

'find an element with given class name within a contact element
Function subValue(IEDocument As Object, classNM As String)
    Dim els As IHTMLElementCollection
    Set els = IEDocument.getElementsByClassName(classNM)
    If els.Length > 0 Then
        subValue = Trim(els(0).innerText)
    Else
        subValue = "[not present]" 'or leave as empty string
    End If
End Function
```

### List of changes:

- Changed the `els` variable type (Object > IHTMLElementCollection)
- Left out the `Function NextEmptyRow()` (which probably works but my part of the code was already working)
- Declared the `IEDocument` variable as a public `HTMLDocument` variable

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but some suggestions here:

Edit - removed the second instance of IE, which I think you don't need.

```vb
Sub ScrapingScript()

    Dim InternetWindow As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim SecondInternetWindow As Object
    Dim IEDocument As HTMLDocument
    Dim BDDsheet As Worksheet
    Dim emptyRow As Range
    
    Set InternetWindow = FindingExistingIE("AmazingWebsite")
    If InternetWindow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "IE window not found!", vbExclamation
    End If
    Set IEDocument = InternetWindow.Document
    
    Set BDDsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AmazingWebsiteSheet")
    BDDsheet.Activate
    
    For Each Contact In AllContacts
        Set emptyRow = NextEmptyRow(BDDsheet, 1)
        
        emptyRow.Cells(1).Value = emptyRow.Row - 1
        'try to find child elements of Contact, based on css class name
        emptyRow.Cells(16).Value = subValue(Contact, "Telephone Number")
        emptyRow.Cells(17).Value = subValue(Contact, "email ng-scope")
        'etc etc
    Next Contact

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

'find an eleemnt with given class name within a contact element
Function subValue(elContact As Object, classNM As String)
    Dim els As Object
    Set els = elContact.getElementsByClassName(classNM)
    If els.Length > 0 Then
        subValue = Trim(els(0).innerText)
    Else
        subValue = "[not present]" 'or leave as empty string
    End If
End Function

'get next empty row at bottom of sheet
Function NextEmptyRow(ws As Worksheet, col As Long)
    Dim rw As Range
    Set rw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).EntireRow
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0 'make sure whole row is empty
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1)
    Loop
    Set NextEmptyRow = rw
End Function
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Williams! Sorry for the late response, I tried running the code a few times until it finally worked! I wasn't very familiar with the Functions so I used your `Function subValue()`, changed the variable type of `els` as an `IHTMLElementCollection`, and left out the `Function NextEmptyRow()` (since that part of the code was already working). Will post the updated code underneath.